# Need help finding an XPATH - Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Been trying different combinations, from find.element_by_xpath and by_id, and for some reason I just can't select the first radio button from this list. It says path cannot be found.

This is the code and I basically need first input to be selected.

```
<li id="opc-shipping_method" class="section">
    <div class="step-title">
        <span class="number">4</span>
        <h3>Shipping Method</h3>
        <!--<a href="#">Edit</a>-->
    </div>
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="">
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">



<dl class="sp-methods">

        <div class="method-option">
            <ul>
                                                                <li>

                                                        <label for="s_method_ups_65">


                                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="ups_65" id="s_method_ups_65" class="radio"/>



                                                                    UPS Saver                                                                                                            <span class="price">€33.34</span>                                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                                                <li>

                                                        <label for="s_method_ups_07">


                                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="ups_07" id="s_method_ups_07" class="radio"/>



                                                                    UPS Express                                                                                                            <span class="price">€35.42</span>                                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                                                <li>

                                                        <label for="s_method_ups_08">


                                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="ups_08" id="s_method_ups_08" class="radio"/>



                                                                    UPS Expedited                                                                                                            <span class="price">€158.37</span>                                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                                                <li>

                                                        <label for="s_method_ups_54">


                                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="ups_54" id="s_method_ups_54" class="radio"/>



                                                                    UPS Worldwide Express PlusSM                                                                                                            <span class="price">€226.73</span>                                                                    </label>
                                                </li>
                                </ul>
        </div>
        </dl>
```

Comment: What XPath have you tried?

Comment: I tried by ID, by xpath, similar to the ones posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="radio"]')[0]
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id("s_method_ups_65")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="s_method_ups_65"]/input')
```

Comment: None of those work. For the first, the error is TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing. And for the others selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[@for=\"s_method_ups_65\"]/input"}

Comment: @Christian, this is because you try `find_element` instead of `find_elements`

Comment: @Christian, Check whether required element located in `iframe` or not

Comment: Tried find_elements, and I get this TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing. No iframe from what I can tell